# How to set operation id for custom application insight events?

Tags: python, flask, azure-application-insights, azure-webapps

We have running on Azure a Python Web App (flask). It processes requests and also logs some results in the end via a custom event to Application Insights.

However inside Application Insights our end-to-end transaction Operation ID for our Custom Events is 0.

[image]

Other event types such as Requests, do have the operation id. How can we get the same operation id in here as the Request event?

```
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureEventHandler, AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger.addHandler(AzureEventHandler(
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'))

def track_result(result):
    properties = {'result': result}
    logger.info('Result log', extra={'custom_dimensions': properties})
    return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here using `openCensus` and `AzureEventHandler`  the operation ID was populated in application insights using the following code :

```
import  logging
from opencensus.trace import config_integration
from  opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter  import  AzureEventHandler
config_integration.trace_integrations(['logging'])

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

handler = AzureEventHandler(connection_string='Connection String from portal')

logger.addHandler(handler)


# Now we can log like this 

logger.warning('Before the span')
```

- Here the operation Id is filled every time I make a get request to my flask api

[image]

Comment: But why are the same? How to start new operation ID?